# Receiving "nonexisting field" error when using Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

When using the Instagram API to retrieve basic info about our own business account (/?fields=instagram_business_account) we are returned the following error:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (InstagramUser)
```

Can anyone shed any light on what might be going on here - are we missing some configuration on our side?

Damien

Answer (score 1):

- Open Facebook Page
- Open Instagram profile and convert business profile
- Instagram profile connect to Facebook page
- Go to Graph API Explorer
- Get token by your app (you have to add manage_pages permission)
- Choose Facebook Page
- Get "me?fields=instagram_accounts{username,id,follow_count,followed_by_count}"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Eventually i figured out it i was using the username instead of the business id.

from the API [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery):

"...Notice that business discovery queries are performed on the Instagram Business or Creator Account's ID ..., not the username of the Instagram Business or Creator Account that you are attempting to get data about..."

To get the Business ID you can use the following query (note that you need to replace your_valid_access_token_here with your valid access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/syriancc?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=your_valid_access_token_here

the json result will look like this:

```
{
   "id": the_actual_id
}
```